# nginx proxy to nginx-ingress

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I setup Virtual machine with Nginx to do Load Balancer to  k&8 nginx ingress

I'm using Cloudflare with multi domains and point to the Proxy Server.

and from the Proxy server it goes to nginx ingress without any issue.

only issue that i have is the Client Ip.

in the file "/var/log/nginx/access.log" i see the real client ip.

but on the nginx-ingress i see the local IP insted of the real IP.

how can i fix that?

thanks!

here is my nginx conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http {
    # CLOUDFLARE
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
    set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

    # LOG FORMAT
    log_format access '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    upstream nodes {
        least_conn;
        server 192.168.10.2:443;
    }

    server {
        listen *:80;
        listen *:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://nodes;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log access;
    }
}
```